# Boldface and Italics not showing in self-defined font

Tags: fonts

I have the following setting in my `init.el` so that tables with Chinese characters can be displayed properly.

```el
(set-face-attribute
 'default nil
 :font (font-spec :name "-*-Menlo-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"
                  :weight 'normal
                  :slant 'normal
                  :size 24))
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (dolist (charset '(kana han symbol cjk-misc bopomofo))
      (set-fontset-font
       (frame-parameter nil 'font)
       charset
       (font-spec :name "-*-STFangsong-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1"
          :weight 'normal
          :slant 'normal
          :size 28))))
```

The table display works perfectly, but I am not able to use emphases with the new font.

[image: emacs]

I know the `STFangsong` font supports bold and italic because they display properly in LibreWriter.

[image: libreoffice]

Does this have something to do with my settings?

---

Running this code, however, fixes the Chinese font italics issue but breaks the English font bold.

```el
(defvar emacs-english-font "Monaco"
  "The font name of English.")

(defvar emacs-cjk-font "STFangsong"
  "The font name for CJK.")

(setq emacs-cjk-font "STFangsong")

(defvar emacs-font-size-pair '(26 . 32)
  "Default font size pair for (english . chinese)")

(setq emacs-font-size-pair '(26 . 32))

(defvar emacs-font-size-pair-list
  '(( 5 .  6) (10 . 12)
    (13 . 16) (15 . 18) (17 . 20)
    (19 . 22) (20 . 24) (21 . 26)
    (24 . 28) (26 . 32) (28 . 34)
    (30 . 36) (34 . 40) (36 . 44))
  "This list is used to store matching (englis . chinese) font-size.")

(defun font-exist-p (fontname)
  "Test if this font is exist or not."
  (if (or (not fontname) (string= fontname ""))
      nil
    (if (not (x-list-fonts fontname)) nil t)))

(defun set-font (english chinese size-pair)
  "Setup emacs English and Chinese font on x window-system."

  (if (font-exist-p english)
      (set-frame-font (format "%s:pixelsize=%d" english (car size-pair)) t))

  (if (font-exist-p chinese)
      (dolist (charset '(kana han symbol cjk-misc bopomofo))
        (set-fontset-font (frame-parameter nil 'font) charset
                          (font-spec :family chinese :size (cdr size-pair))))))

;; Setup font size based on emacs-font-size-pair
(set-font emacs-english-font emacs-cjk-font emacs-font-size-pair)
```

[image: bold for menlo also not functioning]

---

## Test data:

```
Test data. 測試文字
*This is in bold 這是粗體*
/This is in italics 這是斜體/
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. But does the font you have actually have a bold or italic variant? In other words, does is support bold and italic?

Comment: If the `STFangsong` in librewriter is the same as the one used in emacs, then yes, apparently.

Comment: Seems like this is a bug with [`cnfonts`](https://github.com/tumashu/cnfonts/issues/102#issuecomment-484027110)